# Freestanding deck - should I use joist hangers or bugle screws to attach joists to the bearers?

Tags: deck, fastener, decking

I'm planning a freestanding deck in the back yard, and I noticed that in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=4&v=WrguysCWQ1w) they suggested that you could use bugle screws instead of joist hangers. Since I don't have a ledger board at either side, this seems a lot simpler, but will they last? Are there any pros or cons I should know about?

For example, will it be ok to stagger the joists at the middle bearer (there will be three bearers). If I'm not using hangers this will be necessary.

The framing timber I'm probably going to use is cypress, so not the hardest wood around.

Comment: How much weight are you going to out on it?

Comment: just domestic use, chairs, people. It's only about a metre high at the highest point, and one edge will be on the ground. But U'd like it to last, so I think hangers will be the go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your local building codes, but most places in the US, they will insist on the joist hangers.  Joist hangers are far stronger and safer.

They are not that much more trouble, in fact they may be easier to work with.  You can put them in half way, set the jousts in, then finish attaching them.